# How do I install and configure Huawei mobile broadband usb modem?

Tags: huawei, cdma

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and have a Zantel modem (model: Huawei ec122) which is a cdma 1x evdo modem. I have been trying to connect to the Internet but every time it loads it says "network disconnected" (huawei mobile broadband model:huawei ec122 cdma 1x evdo)

Comment: Do not use all caps in your title. Also try to include more information. Any specific errors would be helpful."It no worky" doesn't give people much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

@user154753 just download the package from here and install it manually http://namakutux.blogspot.in/2012/07/bam-huawei-mobile-partner-for-linux.html